# Python exception:"TypeError: main() got an unexpected keyword argument 'debug'" but IFF the module is run via scheduledTask on Windows XP SP2

Tags: python, exception

Running Python 2.5 on Windows XP SP2.

When I run a Python script that calls a user-defined module called `Zipper.py` (basically a wrapper for a zipfile) using a Windows scheduledTask I get this exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>          File "C:\PythonScripts\ZipAndSendEOD-Reports.py", line 78, in main
>              Zipper.main([report],f, debug=True) #[:-4] + "_" + str(x) + ".zip")
>   TypeError: main() got an unexpected keyword argument 'debug'

The odd thing is that if I simply open the file in [IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_%28Python%29) and hit 'F5', it runs flawlessly.

I'm sure I left out some pertinent information, please let me know what you need.

`Zipper.py` looks like this:

```
import zipfile

def main(archive_list=[],zfilename='default.zip', debug=False):
    if debug:    print 'file to zip', zfilename
    zout = zipfile.ZipFile(zfilename, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for fname in archive_list:
        if debug:    print "writing: ", fname
        zout.write(fname)
    zout.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

EDIT:
I added the following two lines of code to the calling function, and it now works.

```
f =  open(logFile, 'a')
f.write(Zipper.__file__)
```

Can you explain THAT to me?

Comment: Uhm,... I don't understand, does Zipper.main take a debug a argument or not?

Comment: Have your script print Zipper.__file__ and make sure it's importing the file you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Paul said, you're probably running a different version of `Zipper.py` - I would print out `Zipper.__file__` and then if you need to debug, print out `sys.path` to see why it's finding a different file.